# Lumx animation not working

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, django, lumx

I am using Django, angularJS and lumx to create a website. I am pretty new to this framework and I am trying to get the basic lumx functionality to work. I installed lumx using the instructions http://ui.lumapps.com/getting-started/installation (using "bower install lumx"). Django is setup to handle the static files correctly.

I have my base.html file that I want to test (should only show a dropdown box):

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="{% static 'browse/js/script.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'browse/bower_components/lumx/dist/lumx.css' %}">

    <script src="{% static 'browse/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'browse/bower_components/velocity/velocity.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'browse/bower_components/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'browse/bower_components/angular/angular.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'browse/bower_components/lumx/dist/lumx.js' %}"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <lx-dropdown over-toggle="true">
        <button class="btn btn--m btn--black btn--flat" lx-ripple lx-dropdown-toggle>
            Dropdown toggle
        </button>

        <lx-dropdown-menu>
            <ul>
            <li><a class="dropdown-link" ng-click="dropdownAlert()">Notification</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-link">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-link">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-link">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-link">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><span class="dropdown-link dropdown-link--is-header">Header</span></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-link">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </lx-dropdown-menu>
    </lx-dropdown>
</body>
```

However the animation does not work, I am not sure what is wrong. None of the lumx animation work (like button ripple) but I am able to call the icons they have. The server logs show all of my css and js files are getting called.

Comment: Are you running this locally? Can you open a web-inspector to check if there are any errors when you load this page?

Comment: @djq I am running it locally with "python manage.py runserer" like normal. The web-inspector is now showing an errors in the files, the JS files are found but I don't they are getting used.

Comment: It's very hard to say what's going wrong with this, from here. I would suggest commenting out all libraries, and loading each library one by one, and outputting something in your browser using `console.log()`. For example, it could be a timing issue (are the libraries loaded when visting the page?), or many other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because you did not initialize Angular correctly. You need to:

- Declare your app with `ngApp` directive
- Declare `lumx` as a dependency of your app (maybe you did in `script.js`?)
- Make sure you call `angular` **after** the library is loaded. Right now your `script.js` is before the load of all libraries.

So a fixed version of your head might be like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'browse/bower_components/lumx/dist/lumx.css' %}">

    <script src="{% static 'browse/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'browse/bower_components/velocity/velocity.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'browse/bower_components/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'browse/bower_components/angular/angular.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'browse/bower_components/lumx/dist/lumx.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'browse/js/script.js' %}"></script>

</head>
```

With something like this in `script.js`:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['lumx']);
```

Comment: That explains a lot, I did have angular.module('myApp', ['lumx']); decaled but I didn't fully understand how to use "ng-app" at the time. Thank you!